# How can I eagerly load navigation property when joining on columns with different types using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core

We have a legacy database and we have requirements to interact with that database as read-only to get some data(we can't change its schema).

There are tables that are not associated with each other using FKs but using values of column and unfortunately, Primary key and related column on the dependent table have different data types(ex char and nvarchar).

Using **Entity Framework Core** I wrote some mapping like following:

```
EntityTypeBuilder<Supplier>.HasMany(x => x.CatalogueItems)
        .WithOne(x => x.Supplier)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.Vendor);
```

But when I try to eagrly loading navigation properties using **Include** method:

```
dbContext.CatalogueItems.Include(x => x.Supplier).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get Supplier as null, and when I write it using projection I get Supplier data:

```
dbContext.CatalogueItems.Select(x => new {
                               x.ItemCode,
                               x.Supplier 
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Could you please tell me how can I tweak it to get navigation properties using Include?

**Edit:**

Startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));

        services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Add application services.

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share startup.cs also

Comment: Can you try `var item = (from obj in dbContext.CatalogueItems.Include(s => s.Supplier)
   select obj).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: I have tried it. it didn't work Supplier returned null

Comment: Is Supplier mapped with CatalogueItems. Can you check in DB whether you are getting proper tables with columns and relationships

Comment: Yea, as I mentioned in my question I can get the related Supplier when I get a CatalogueItem

Comment: Better you raise a bug for EF Core?